# How to warn at compile time when a using directive is used or when a type is referenced?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use a legacy NuGet packed which depends on *Log4Net*.

In my .net Framework application I use *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging* and *SeriLog*.

Visual Studio intellisense when I type *ILogger* interface, tries to suggest me to use *Log4Net* and others which I do not desire to use as they would lead to errors.

I am looking for a way possibly in visual studio to warn when you select one of the black listed types coming from assemblies I do not want to use. But the actual change should go along with the source code.

I searched online, tried to review compiler directives and options but I could not find a way.

At the moment until I get rid of the legacy NuGet I cannot achieve it, but I would like to prevent it as I am afraid other developers will ignore the readme.md and go straight with the first suggested import... which obviously is always the wrong one.

Comment: There isn't this kind of granularity available. But really, code review is the only solution.

Comment: you can write a Roslyn analyzer to do this, but it isn't trivial